# Hadoop : How to set/change the trash folder?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I knew that the default trash folder location is set to `/user/<computer-name>/.Trash` on Hdfs.

I want to know **how to set/change the Hadoop trash folder to our own HDFS path or LFS path?**

Comment: Path are /user/<username>/.Trash. It is required to be in the user home directory for security reasons: only this user can see trashed files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't. It's hard coded in HDFS https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/7016dd44e0975274856dc19f19815123c4b2a352/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.java